# Mysql Erro - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, conexão, microsoft-access, password

Bom dia pessoal,
Estou preciso muito desta ajuda, por favor.

Arquivo: c:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin4.9.2\config.inc.php
Aqui está o início do código:

```
if($wampConf['SupportMySQL'] == 'on') {
/* Server: localhost [1] */
    $i++;
    if($mariaFirst) $i++;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'MySQL';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = $wampConf['mysqlPortUsed'];
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '123';
```

**Se uso a senha no usuário root:**
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
**Se não faço uso de senha no usuário root:**
Unknown database 'mydb'

> Já desinstalei tudo e reinstalei novamente, por duas vezes e nada de funcionar.

Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver este erro. Estou parado no meu projeto por alguns dias, já tentei de várias explicações da internet e nada de solução.

Estou usando a versão do Wampserver 3.2.0 64bit

Answer (score -1):

Você fez a primeira configuração, que é do wamp para o MySQL. Agora precisa atribuir a senha dentro do MySQL. Por padrão usa-se user root, sem senha. É apenas uma dica, pois uso o XAMPP e tem me resolvido muito o problema. Nessa semana comecei a aprender o Docker para hospedar em Linux, caso queira mudar a tecnologia do seu projeto avisa que a gente bate um papo. Tente o XAMPP, é mais fácil. Para acessar o Bando uso o Heidi (gratuito) em vez do phpMyAdmin, e para modelagem uso o Workbench (gratuito da Oracle). Não deixe seu projeto parado por causa da Infra, procure outras alternativas.

Comment: Bom dia Renato, te agradeço pela atenção.
Consegui resolver, valeu...

Irei deixar aqui um post, como foi a solução, por motivo de fazer uma pergunta, mas que parte do erro era por outro assunto.

Se for possível, irei postar aqui uma imagem para dar maior clareza no erro, acredito que muitos passam por isto, e é algo muito simples, que pode causar uma grande perda de tempo como foi o que passei.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, por favor descreva a solução, com certeza vai ajudar alguém.

Comment: Solucionado o Erro: Na verdade era causado não por erros de senha ou privilégios de usuário, mas sim, pela questão da nona versão do Wampserver 3.2.0

Onde que ficou ativado o banco de dados MariaDB.

Caso esteja usando o bd MySQL, a pessoa cria novo bd, com senha ou sem senha e
o erro persiste.

Simples a solução:

Vamos no ícone do Wampserver, clicar com o botão direito e escolher:
Tools/Inverter default DBMS MariaDB < - > MySQL
Irá reiniciar o Wampserver.

Pronto, com isto foi solucionado o erro.


![Inverter MariaDB para MySQL](https://imgur.com/BwhbTXx)